# How to get WMO SYNOP data?

Tags: data, web-service, weather

I would like to get WMO weather stations observations daily reports from the web in file or web-service form.
According to WMO Resolution 40 -[info](http://www.wmo.int/pages/about/Resolution40_en.html)- this data should be availiable in text form with SYNOP codes.

Does anyone know a place to look for this data?

I've looked through NCEP and NASA sites, and didn't find the dataset itself.

I've found only http://www.ogimet.com site, that provides data in html and txt form, but you have to specify a WMO station index or a region - so no service for global coverage (all WMO stations). I suppose this site gets information from the resource, that I'm looking for.

Comment: Looks like the link to Resolution 40 was affected by link rot on WMO website. Currently (September 2023) the text can be found at the [following link](https://community.wmo.int/en/resolution-40).

Answer (score 1):

SYNOP data (and some data from ships and mobile land stations) in text form from the last 25 hours is (re-)published by the [NWS department of the NOAA](http://tgftp.nws.noaa.gov/SL.us008001/DF.an/DC.sflnd/DS.synop/). Note that SYNOP in text form (Traditional Alphanumeric Code, TAC) is being replaced by the BUFR format; some countries (e.g. Germany) have stopped to provide TAC. NOAA also has [BUFR data](http://tgftp.nws.noaa.gov/SL.us008001/DF.bf/DC.intl/).

Note that this data is still owned by the original provider, further processing may be restricted.

Answer (score 0):

this site will give you hourly observations for up to 4000 synop observations at the main hours of 0000,0600,1200,1800.

http://weather.cod.edu/digatmos/syn/
I started developing mapping programs about 1990 which grew into
a very complex system used by many amateurs as well as some
private forecasting companies.
due to the lack of support by Microsoft Visual Basic 6 was no longer
usable on later versions of windows and I was forced to cease further development.
a few urls are now out of date but 95% of the system still works. 
The system METEOSCREEN COLLECTS THE DATA AUTOMATICALLY AND THEN PLOTS A VARIETY OF MAPS FOR THAT HOUR. I AM NO LONGER FULLY SUPOORTING IT BUT I AM WILLING TO GIVE SOME BASIC HELP TO GET IT GOING. IT ALSO DOES METARS.

Comment: Please, [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/260814/edit) your post and fix grammar and uppercase.